# 'Pause' activity while waiting for PictureCallback to occur

Tags: android, callback, android-camera

I'm building an Android app where I would like to wait for the PictureCallback to occur before the calling activity continues.

```
import android.hardware.Camera;

private Camera camera
private Bitmap picture;

camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length, options);
  }
}

... do some other logic with picture
```

I would like to keep the other logic seperated and thus I would like to avoid coding this in the takePicture function.

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same. Good question.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to block the UI thread while you do any background work.

If you call the built in Camera activity, your activity will be in the background. After you took the picture and the camera activity closes, by the time you get back to your activity the picture will be already saved.

If you use your own `Camera` implementation then you should display a `ProgressDialog` and if you have any background work to do, you should do it in a separate thread.

Comment: I'm indeed using my own Camera implementation. I don't see how using a ProgressDialog could fix this problem.
The way the code is executed is as following:
 1) take picture
 2) do the next logic
 3) callback returns picture
I would like it in following order: 1 3 2

Comment: I misunderstood your question so it seems. But then you can just write your 2) in a separate method and call it in the end of the callback function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Your suggestion could be a solution, but the reason why I'm having so much trouble is because I'm trying to keep my code so abstract as possible.
In my project I have an Activity and a separated Camera-class. I'm calling the takePicture function in the Camera class, who would then have to wait for the callback, followed by returning the picture to the activity. The problem is that the code in the activity AFTER calling the takePicture is executed BEFORE the callback has a chance to return the bitmap.
Tell me if you would prefer to see the complete code.

Comment: I understand, but then you could maybe pass your activity, or a separate class with the 2) code, initialized in your activity to your Camera class constructor, and execute that, in the callback. This is one way. If it's too vague, post your code and I can write some solutions based on that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it in two threads. Then right after the PictureCallback is called call wait() on the current thread. Then when PictureCallback is finished have it call notify() to let the waiting thread know its ok to finish. But you dont want to block your main thread. You can if you want/need too but its not a good idea.

Comment: I've tried implementing the PictureCallback in a different thread but that didn't work out. Somehow the callbacks are always run in the main thread.